# Data Type conversion of columns in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a pipe delimited file.
I want to store the records of this file in sql server table.
Schema of my table is already decided.I want to change the datatypes of the columns retrieved from file before storing data into table.

There are some ways I know , we can do
Data Conversion tool but problem this component is if column is blank and I want to store it into numeric(18,0) column then it not working.
Any suggestion how I can achieve this task?

Comment: What is the source and destination data type for the column ?

Comment: Source is string which is having blank value and destination is numeric and similarly source is string as blank spaces & destination is datetime..

Comment: it will be better a derived column component as you can manipulate the input with expressions

Comment: `ISNULL(SourceColumn) || SourceColumn == " "  ? 0 : SourceColumn`

Comment: i'd also add a trim just in case there is more than one space ISNULL(SourceColumn) || TRIM(SourceColumn) == "" ? 0 : SourceColumn

Answer (score 0):

First use a derived column. and within the derived column expression you check the input value, if its length is zero, or the content isNull then set the value to 0 (with a decimal type). ELSE you retrive the value of the input column as it is with numeric values conditions that you want.

```
LEN([Column 1]) == 0 || ISNULL([Column 1]) ? 0 : (DT_NUMERIC,18,0)[Column 1]
```

It is important to note: if all your input data are already NULL (BLANK) then you just have to do do the following:

```
NULL(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 0)
```

And here we go, in your case there is **no need** for Data Conversion component ;)

Best Regards,
S.ANDOURA